# Android New Project only themes file

Tags: android, kotlin, android-styles, android-darkmode

I am using the new stable version of Android Studio `4.1.1`. When I create a new Android project, by default there are 2 `themes.xml` files one under `values` and an other under `values-night`. But I don't see the `styles.xml`.

The `themes.xml` looks like this -

```
<style name="Theme.SampleApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

My questions are -

1. Do I need to create a `styles.xml` for my individual views or could I start adding in the `themes.xml` as well?
2. If I need to create a `styles.xml` should I create them one under `values` and an other under `values-night`?
3. Why is the `themes.xml` missing `colorAccent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to create a styles.xml for my individual views or could I start adding in the themes.xml as well?

There is nothing stopping you putting styles for individual views into `themes.xml`. Presumably, Google's vision here is to have theme-related stuff in `themes.xml` and have other styles in a `styles.xml` that you create.

In the end, filenames in `res/values/` and related directories (e.g., `res/values-night/`) do not matter much. You can put styles and themes in `styles.xml`, `themes.xml`, `maria.xml`, or whatever.

> If I need to create a styles.xml should I create them one under values and an other under values-night?

Only if you need to have different styles for regular use and for night mode.

> Why is the themes.xml missing colorAccent?

Android Studio 4.1 is not using `AppCompat` themes. Instead, it is using `MaterialComponents` themes, from the Material Components for Android. Those themes use [a different color system](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/color) than does AppCompat.

Comment: That explains everything...So the colorAccent equivalent would be colorSecondary